# The simple application on Spring Boot and http authentification

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, http-authentication

I'm just starting to learn web programming and I'm trying to write my first application using Spring Boot, which provides a RESTful API for HRM systems. But I have difficulties with HTTP authentication. I tried many guides, but they haven't helped.

Without security setting the RESTful API works, but if I include security for my API I get code 401. How do I fix it?

**[Link to source code](https://gist.github.com/sergey-prosvirnin/e1431f4de14b6c78facf3fb0e23f8449)**

[Screenshot_from_REST_client_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVbQ2.png)
[Screenshot_from_REST_client_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JELm7.png)
[Screenshot_from_REST_client_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoygQ.png)
[Screenshot_from_REST_client_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCcBT.png)

**SpringSecurityConfig.java (without package and import)**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers().permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}


@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

P.S. English isn't my first language, so please be kind to my mistakes. I'm really trying to improve my English.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication) tutorial then come back if you have any further questions.

Comment: Form login is not suitable for API authentication.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, therefore you should read the Spring Boot documentation. There is a chapter explaining how to override Spring Boots's default configuration.